# Why does the Indian Pariah dog go into heat once a year?

Tags: dogs

I read on the net and found that Indian stray dog, named pariah goes into heat once a year during mating season August - Jan. Their gestation period is 2 months so November- December is when most pups are born.

**But why do pariahs, unlike most others go into heat once, and all at the same time?**

You can read about their mating season in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_pariah_dog). I could not find the explanation.
Thank you.

Comment: Basenji's are the same way; typically one litter a year, about the same time as your Indian Pariah's... so, this might be (simply) a breed trait.

Comment: @trondhansen sorry. I asked two separate questions why pups are born togethor and why they go into heat once but since I edited and asked both in that one, what should I do with this question sir? Should I delete it?

Comment: you do not need to remove your question,and others might disagree with me on this being a duplicate :)